# jquery selector to a button with no id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to have a selector to this button (I have no control on the source code of it) so I can't add an id attribute to it.

Also there is nothing that I can point to before or after the button and also I cant rely on the inner text (its multi-language site- so the text can change)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary-gray btn-sm ng-binding" href=""
        ng-click="switchPanels('addresses')">Address book</button>
```

I thought to look for a button with

```
ng-click="switchPanels('addresses')
```

This is my best option? and if so, how can I look for it?

Comment: You have the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: `$("button[ng-click=\"switchPanels('addresses')\"]")` should do it

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment. its the error that i am getting when runing this

Comment: There's no end of ways to select an element in jQuery. I suggest you read the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @Rajesh i have no control on the source code of that appliction

Comment: "there is nothing that I can point to before or after the button" .... sure there is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a selector for the classes and the `ng-click` parameter if you want to be as precise as possible.

This would look like this:

`button[ng-click="switchPanels('addresses')"].btn.btn-primary-gray.btn-sm.ng-binding`

Proof of concept:

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($("button[ng-click=\"switchPanels('addresses')\"].btn.btn-primary-gray.btn-sm.ng-binding"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary-gray btn-sm ng-binding" href="" ng-click="switchPanels('addresses')">Address book</button>
```

Comment: i will use this selector `$("button[ng-click=\"switchPanels('addresses')\"]")` The classes after it dont mather. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `$('...["..."]')`

Comment: sure! ill mark .. please also change the text in the answer- `button[ng-click="switchPanels('addresses')"]` to `$("button[ng-click=\"switchPanels('addresses')\"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("btn.btn-primary-gray.btn-sm.ng-binding")?
```

selects by a combination of classes. But that is not the best idea as multiple buttons can have the same combination.

```
$("button[ng-click=\"switchPanels('addresses')\"]")
```

Noticed the edit: This is what you asked in it. Altho, keep in mind as soon as you change ANYTHING in ng-click or decide to go with something else for the event it will not work.

I am not sure I would couple myself like that. **You are mixing the event (on-action) bindings to the controller's function with the jQuery selector for the element.** This sounds like a terrible idea.

Good question since you are using Angular, WHY do you need jQuery in the 1st place? Angular is convention over configuration framework and prefers to do things in its own way instead of using jQuery to accomplish the same.

Make sure you have tried doing this the Angular way.

Comment: in my app i dont use `angularJS` and in the app that i need to get selector to - it uses angularJS - i have no other choice as they are not the same application

Comment: That's an odd situation. Who decided to develop 2 different apps over the same HTML? Basically, as soon as someone edits HTML for the 1st app, the second one is gonna fall apart and vice versa. I can think of very few situations when I would do something like this. Especially when they go over exactly the same blocks of HTML. What is a guy who makes 1st app decided to let's say rename his ng-click function, or the parameter or even removes the entire button for something else?

Comment: yes- "an odd situation" but, it is what it is... the app follow this modal: there is a base app (uses angular) , and the other app(s) are "extensions" to add functionality to the base application, customer buy the base app and from there he can add an "abilities" that extend the base app.

Comment: Tell to whoever decided to do it like that there are far better models to handle solutions like that from an architecture point of view.  Some that come to mind. Different versions of app builds with different features. One app with server-side enabled additional features (some user have some functionality, others have more, rest is locked on the back-end) and more. You are basically begging for maintenance hell.

Comment: the base app and the all of other applications company were separate. now they are not (they all belong to the base app company) > so this is the result :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this 2 ways:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).attr('ng-click') == "switchPanels('addresses')"){
      console.log('address btn')
    }
  });
});

$('button[ng-click="switchPanels(\'addresses\')"]').html('Address Book text changed')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary-gray btn-sm ng-binding" href="" 
          ng-click="switchPanels('addresses')">Address book</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Do the parents of the button have id?

If yes, so:

```
var sender = $("#parent_id > button");
```

Search a parent_id in the parents of the parents.

Comment: Please read the question properly *there is nothing that I can point to before or after the button*